# If a form field has multi validators, how to let play verify them one by one, not all?

Tags: validation, playframework-2.0

I have a login form in view, there is a `name` input has many validators:

```
object Users extends Controller {

    val loginForm = Form(tuple(
        "name" -> ( 
            nonEmptyText // (1)
            verifying ("Its length should >= 4", name=>{ println("#222");name.length>=4 }) // (2)
            verifying ("It should have numbers and letters", name=>{println("#333"); ...}) // (3)
        )
}
```

Then I don't input anything, press submit, and I found the console prints:

```
#222
#333
```

That means all validators performed, and they have relationship:

```
(1) & (2) & (3)
```

But I hope they:

```
(1) && (2) && (3)
```

That means, if the name is empty, the later two validators will be ignored.

Is it possible in play2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior is to apply all the constraints defined on a field.
However, you can define your own validation constraint that stops applying constraints on the first fail:

```scala
def stopOnFirstFail[T](constraints: Constraint[T]*) = Constraint { field: T =>
  constraints.toList dropWhile (_(field) == Valid) match {
    case Nil => Valid
    case constraint :: _ => constraint(field)
  }
}
```

It can be used like the following:

```scala
val loginForm = Form(
  "name" -> (text verifying stopOnFirstFail(
    nonEmpty,
    minLength(4)
  ))
)
```

```scala
scala> loginForm.bind(Map("name"->"")).errors
res2: Seq[play.api.data.FormError] = List(FormError(name,error.required,WrappedArray()))

scala> loginForm.bind(Map("name"->"foo")).errors
res3: Seq[play.api.data.FormError] = List(FormError(name,error.minLength,WrappedArray(4)))

scala> loginForm.bind(Map("name"->"foobar")).errors
res4: Seq[play.api.data.FormError] = List()
```

(Note that my implementation of `stopOnFirstFail` applies two times the failing constraint, so this one should not have side effects)

Comment: Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759660/how-to-define-a-stoponfirstfail-dsl-for-play2s-form