# How to define a StopOnFirstFail dsl for play2's form?

Tags: forms, validation, playframework-2.0

In this question: [If a form field has multi validators, how to let play verify them one by one, not all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750562/if-a-form-field-has-multi-validators-how-to-let-play-verify-them-one-by-one-no), Julien gave me a method named `stopOnFirstFail` to solve my problem:

```scala
def stopOnFirstFail[T](constraints: Constraint[T]*) = Constraint { field: T =>
  constraints.toList dropWhile (_(field) == Valid) match {
    case Nil => Valid
    case constraint :: _ => constraint(field)
  }
}
```

It's usage is:

```scala
val loginForm = Form(
  "name" -> (text verifying stopOnFirstFail( nonEmpty, minLength(4) ))
)
```

But I hope to define a dsl which can be used as:

```scala
val loginForm = Form(
  "name" -> (text verifying ( nonEmpty or minLength(4) ))
)
```

I tried to defined an implicit method for `play.api.data.validation.Constraint`:

```scala
import play.api.data.validation._

implicit def _Constraint[T](cons: Constraint[T]) = new {

  def or[T](other: Constraint[T]) = Constraint { field: T =>
    cons(field) match {              // (!)
      case Valid => other(field)
      case invalid => invlaid
    }
  }
}
```

But it can't be compiled, the error in on the (!) line, and message is:

```
type mismatch; 
found: field.type (with underlying type T) required: T 
Note: implicit method _Constraint is not applicable here
      because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `or` method does not take a type parameter:

```scala
implicit def toLazyOr[T](cons: Constraint[T]) = new {
  def or(other: Constraint[T]) = Constraint { field: T =>
    cons(field) match {
      case Valid => other(field)
      case Invalid => Invalid
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the last case, what worked for me was to use `case fail@Invalid(_) => fail`. Otherwise it complains that `Invalid` is an object. I'm using scala 2.11.11

Comment: A better name for this would have been `and`. `or` seems to suggest that if one fails, then the other should be attempted, whereas that's the opposite of what the OP intended

Answer (score 0):

```
  def stopOnFirstFail[T](constraints: Constraint[T]*) = Constraint { field: T =>
    var result: ValidationResult = null
    val loop = new Breaks
    loop.breakable(
      for (constrain <- constraints) {
        result = constrain(field)
        if (result != Valid) {
          loop.break()
        }
      }
    )
    if (result == null) Valid else result
  }
```

this implementations makes validations just once :)