# How to call this scala method in play?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I came across the below method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759660/how-to-define-a-stoponfirstfail-dsl-for-play2s-form?rq=1:)

```
 implicit def toLazyOr[T](cons: Constraint[T]) = new {
  def or(other: Constraint[T]) = Constraint { field: T =>
    cons(field) match {
      case Valid => other(field)
      case Invalid => Invalid
    }
  }
}
```

I defined `toLazyOr` method and then I am trying to use it in my code. But, I am not sure how do I use this.
I tried:

```
 val adminForm = Form(
mapping(
  "email" -> (email verifying toLazyOr(nonEmpty, minLength(4)) ) 
  )
```

And:

```
val adminForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "email" -> (email verifying toLazyOr(nonEmpty or minLength(4)) ) 
      )
```

Both are not working and my scala knowledge for the moment is very basic. 
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing very much about play:

If the implicit conversion is in scope, the following should work:

```
val adminForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "email" -> (email verifying (nonEmpty or minLength(4)))
  ))
```

That's the thing about implicit conversions: You don't have to call them explicitly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits/5598107#5598107) for more information about where the compiler is looking for implicits.